# Error deleteRowsAtIndexPaths from UITable

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

I am having a big issue trying to delete from an UITableView.

Just for note, I have the same code running fine on another view and thats why it's making me crazy.

The only difference is that on the other view, my array is in a property. But I tried changing my tmpArray to a property and nothing changed. Here's the code and the error after:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [tmpArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tbvPlaylist deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

Error:

> *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1912.3/UITableView.m:1046

Let me now if you need more info.

Comment: Is `tmpArray` the array that returns it's count in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`? The tableview will look at the changes you make and ensure they match up with the info provided by the datasource calls e.g. if you remove one row using `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` it is expected that the datasource will reflect this change also

Comment: Hmmm, I understand what you are asking, but I'm not sure about the answer. How am I supposed to bind the tmpArray.count to the count that deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation is expecting?

Comment: But anyway I guess the answer is yes. tmpArray is the one that would reflect the changes of deleteRowsAtIndexPath.
My test: my table have 10 rows, if I delete one, the tmpArray goes to 9 and the tableView:numberOfRowsInSection should be 9 after calling deleteRowsAtIndexPath:withRowAnimation:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `tmpArray` the same ivar that is providing the count of rows e.g.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    return tmpArray.count;
}
```

Also at the moment you call

```
[tbvPlaylist deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

`tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` should return the

```
numberOfRowsBeforeDelete - numberOfRowsBeingDeleted
```

Comment: nice, works like a charm. That was the problem, since I have this tmpArray that comes from 2 different array depending on the circumstances, I forgot to change tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: to: return tmpArray.count;